# Regex search: word with open ending

Tags: php, regex, search

i have a array with values like this:

```
$needles = array(
    'hide',
    'foo',
    'bar'
);
```

And i want to search for these needles in a string like this:

```
$string = 'lets unhide this div';

foreach( $needles as $needle ):

    if( strpos( $string, $needle ) ) echo 'do stuff';

endforeach;
```

This works pretty well so far but there is the problem that the unhide in the example above is catched but it shouldn't. I know that i simply could add white spaces around the needles but heres the thing:

The search should catch words with that beginning (hide and not **un**hide) but should left the ending of the word open so that hide**ous** will be catched ... that makes probably no sense in english i know but thats exactly the behaviour i need (cause it works very well in german).

So i need a regex like this:

```
if( strpos( preg_match( 'stringstartorwhitespace|'.$needle.'|anythingexceptwhitespace|whitespace' ), $string ) ) echo 'do stuff';
```

Here are some results

```
schön in schön = 1
schön in unschön = 0
schön in schönes = 1
schön in schönstes = 1
schön in schönem = 1
```

Comment: i think you need **[this](https://regex101.com/r/eU4wZ6/1)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Till I understand, you require [*word boundary*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) which is denoted as `\b`. The regex will be

```
\bschön
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eU4wZ6/1)**

*PHP Code*

```
$re = "/\\bschön/"; 
$str = array("schön", "unschön", "schönes", "schönstes", "schönem");

foreach ($str as $x) {
    if (preg_match($re, $x)) {
        print($x."\n");
    }
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/HLIgVT)**

Comment: @Grandy no worries..don't forget to accept and upvote

Comment: Jep ... just want to try it in my application before i vote it ;)

Comment: I seriously should get into regex but it is so complicated ._.

Comment: Ha! I started reading on this topic several times ... the only thing would enjoy with regex is that it is so mighty =P